# Facebook login on Android TV

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, television

I'm trying to implement the Facebook login on my Android TV app.
I've been following this little guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/devices

But I can't make it work.
Here is a sample of my code:

```
mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    DeviceLoginManager loginManager = new DeviceLoginManager();
    loginManager.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            connectWithFacebook(loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            loginFailed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            loginFailed();
        }
    });
    List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
    permissions.add("email");
    loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(activity, permissions);
```

I'm getting the webview popup with the email and password fields (like on mobile) instead of getting this one:

[facebook login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcciB.png)

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in DeviceLoginManager that I spent a lot of time to find out.

You must to set the LoginBehavior as DEVICE_AUTH before the call of logInWithReadPermissions.

```
loginManager.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.DEVICE_AUTH);
loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(activity, permissions);
```

And, also, add this metaData in your Manifest:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken"
        android:value="@string/client_token" />
```

Probably they'll fix that sometime in the future, since they already did with the DeviceLoginButton